# How to force OmniOS (illumos) "format" properly recognize disk geometry?

Tags: solaris, zfs, illumos, omnios

I have a FreeBSD-initialised 8-disk vdev, all 10TB WD RED, now on a server with OmniOS r151026, connected via LSI 3008 HBA.

At POST, the card shows all disks with right geometry (I can post picture if necessary).

But `format` reports a wrong (~ 2TB) geometry:

```
format
Searching for disks...done

c0t5000CCA26BD0CAFAd0: configured with capacity of 2047.71GB
c0t5000CCA26BD5AAC5d0: configured with capacity of 2047.71GB
c0t5000CCA26BD6B9CCd0: configured with capacity of 2047.71GB
c0t5000CCA26BD6C6D4d0: configured with capacity of 2047.71GB
c0t5000CCA26BD6E59Cd0: configured with capacity of 2047.71GB
c0t5000CCA26BD59F6Dd0: configured with capacity of 2047.71GB
c0t5000CCA26BD116ACd0: configured with capacity of 2047.71GB
c0t5000CCA26BD6960Ed0: configured with capacity of 2047.71GB
```

`format` should instead report something like (only first drive listed):

```
AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t5000CCA26BD0CAFAd0 <ATA-WDC WD100EFAX-68-0A83-9.10TB>
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca26bd0cafa
```

`diskinfo` correctly reports size (showing only first disk):

```
root@omniosce:~# diskinfo -p
TYPE    DISK                    VID      PID              SIZE          RMV SSD
SCSI    c0t5000CCA26BD0CAFAd0   ATA      WDC WD100EFAX-68 10000831348736 no  no
```

How to force OmniOS (illumos) "format" properly recognize disk geometry?

Thank you in advance.

Edit 2018-06-02: Added disk kind and expected result (thanks to @andrew-henle)

Comment: How about telling us what the disks are, and what you think should be reported?

Comment: Thank you, I have edited question and added details, also diskinfo output.

Answer (score 0):

Andy Fiddaman, one of OmniOS maintainers, suggested to use `zpool labelclear`.

That worked perfectly and allowed `format` to properly recognise the disk geometry again.

Thanks to Andy Fiddaman, and thanks to all illumos' developers and maintainers for such an outstanding OS.